# MikroORM Eager is set to false yet the relation is still being loaded

Tags: node.js, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity()
export class SomeEntity extends BaseEntity implements ISomeEntity {
@ManyToOne(() => OtherEntity, {
    nullable: true,
    eager: false
  })
  otherEntity: OtherEntity;
}
```

But `otherEntity` is still loaded when running `findOne` or `find` functions.

I don't know how to stop loading other relations without affecting `where` conditions. As this leads to circular issues.

Based on the decorators here https://mikro-orm.io/docs/decorators/#manytoone

> eager boolean yes Always load the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in MikroORM, it links any relation that was previously loaded automatically regardless the eagerness. This is by design as per [documentation](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/nested-populate).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for this information? Thanks

Comment: I added the link.